# Deleting a folder from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i want to delete a folder from my database when button is clicked.

```
...
<td><%#Eval("FolderId").ToString() %></td>
...
```

I list files using the file ID.

Here is my btnDelete codes;

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand del = new SqlCommand("delete * from Folders where FolderId=@id");
        del.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", ???);
        del.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

What should I write to the `@id` parameter value?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptC" runat="server"> 
  <HeaderTemplate> 
  <center><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="400"> 
  <caption><b>Files</b></caption> 
  <thead> 
  <tr> 
  <th>File ID</th> 
  <th>Path</th> 
  <th>?</th> 
  </tr> 
  </thead> 

  </HeaderTemplate> 
  <ItemTemplate> 
  <tbody> 
  <tr> 
  <td><%#Eval("FolderId").ToString() %></td> 
  <td><%#Eval("FilePath").ToString() %></td>
  <td><asp:Button ID="btnDelete" CssClass="btnH" ForeColor="#ffffff"     BackColor="#ba04c2" Text="Delete" runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_Click"/></td> 

  </tr> 
  </tbody> 
  </ItemTemplate> 
  <FooterTemplate> 
  </table> </center>
  </FooterTemplate> 
  </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: is the button generated automatically depends on how many 'folder's printed? if so, you could use Button's [Command Argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Which do you want: deleting just folder name from DB or also deleting the real folder structure altogether after deletion? You can use a variable e.g. `del.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", folderName);` containing folder name from server control with command argument, then execute query.

Comment: What you mean folder in your DB? You mean a row in the Folder table? Or real operative system folders? Also `DELETE` statement doesnt have `*`

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I want to delete a row from my Folders table, also it must be deleted from the folder named Folders in the solution.

Comment: what you mean folder name Folders? What is your specific problem?

Comment: @M.West - So you have stored some specific folders in a database along with their physical paths, and then you want to delete both the database entry and the physical folder upon a button click?

Comment: Well, I see that you want to delete the `Folders` folder from DB and then delete physical folder with same name from the disk, right? You need 2 queries for that: one to delete (`DELETE FROM`) and one to calling shell (e.g. `EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @removedircommand, no_output`).

Comment: What I mean with "Folders" is, a project folder where files are kept.

I don't know how to introduce the file ID (in the database) to the button.
For deleting a row. Also yes, buttons generated automatically depens on how many folders printed.

Comment: Could you share more markup? Is a repeater? A grid view?

Comment: Yes, it is a repeater, let me add the codes to the question.

Comment: @M.West When you say "project folder", do you mean a Visual Studio project folder? As in one, that is included in the solution of the application, which you are running?

Comment: Yes, it is a project folder.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to implement that is using the Repeater **ItemCommand** event.

Markup

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server" OnItemCommand="repeater_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Text") %>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="DeleteButton"  Text="Text" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code Beside

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    repeater.DataSource = new[] {
        new {Id= 1, Text = "Text 1"  },
        new {Id= 2, Text = "Text 2"  },
    };
    repeater.DataBind();
}

protected void repeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        Response.Write($"Do something with {e.CommandArgument}");
    }

}
```

Source Code here

- https://github.com/kblok/StackOverflowExamples/blob/master/AspNetDemoProject/AspNetDemoProject/Demos/RepeaterDemo.aspx
- https://github.com/kblok/StackOverflowExamples/blob/master/AspNetDemoProject/AspNetDemoProject/Demos/RepeaterDemo.aspx.cs